# Let python check if a condition is True throughout the duration of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, while-loop, browser-automation

The function launch_setup() opens instagram, signs in and performs a few other initial functions. Sometimes, an popup appears in instagram that needs to be closed before proceeding. This can appear anytime. I need to constanly look for the popup and close it if it appears anytime during the function launch_setup(). I need to do the same for function repost_from_hashtag(ele). But the function error_exists() doesnt seem to become true even when the popup appears during any of the function, hence the popup doesnt close and the program halts. I know the problem isn't with identifying the popup since I've tried that before.

```
def error_exists():
      try:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 's4Iyt')
        print('ERROR FOUND')
        return True
      except:
        print('no error')
        return False

def error_solve():
     ok_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF.cB_4K')
     ok_button.click()


while error_exists() == False:
    launch_setup()
else:
    error_solve()

for ele in hashtags:
    while error_exists() == False:
        repost_from_hashtag(ele)
    else:
        error_solve()
```

Comment: How many times do you want to call launch_setup()? What you're doing now is call it over and over until the pop up appears.

Comment: I'd suggest webdriver wait so that you have some checks that occur periodically for the occurence of the element.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks for pointing that out, i just want it to run once but still can't figure out how to continuously check for the popup

Comment: @ArundeepChohan can you show an example?